# Can I control or know the width of the ::marker element?

Tags: html, css

The following screenshot shows what I want to accomplish in terms of styling an unordered list (UL > LI).

I accomplished this with the following code:

```
  ul {
    list-style-position: outside; /** Is the default. */
    padding-left: 18px;
  }

  ul li::marker {
    color: green;
  }
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**The problem with this** is that `18px` is a arbitrary number. If the font-size changes this doesn't work anymore etc.

---

Here is another approach that gets me the following (see screenshot below).

```
  ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  ul li::marker {
    color: green;
  }
```

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

**The problem with this** is that the text wraps underneath the marker/bullet.

The question is, **how can I accomplish the first screenshot, using `::marker`?** In the past I would have gone for a `::before` pseudo element and hacked it together, but I really want to know if I can accomplish this using today's standard.

Comment: Then don't use `px`, use `em` or `rem`.

Comment: You have limited options to style the [`marker`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker) so an alternative approach is probably advisable.

Comment: Doesn't seem to want to take a `width`, even if I add `display: inline-block`. But you could simply position the marker absolute, and give the `li` a padding-left of your liking.

Comment: @CBroe - exactly, ```width``` does not work and ```display``` doesn't either. The absolute position hack is what I wanted to try to avoid (if possible), therefore the question.

Comment: @Paulie_D - using another unit (em, rem, ch) sadly does not solve this issue completely. Using the `ch` unit comes close though. For example: `padding-left: 1.5ch;`.